How to debug a running python program?
I'm a programmer but don't know much about python. The program in question is the a1111 stable diffusion webui and due to hardware quirks I'm running it in an anaconda environment with unsupported library versions. Every now and then, the back end seemingly just hangs when inferencing in a certain way and since I haven't found anyone else describing the same issue, I'm assuming its to do with my environment and how its set up. I'm not expecting this to get fixed by somebody else so I want to go and fix it myself.
TLDR start here:
In order to run the program, I launch anaconda prompt, activate the associated environment and then call python with the associated file name. Since its an interpreted language, I'm assuming its possible to manually break the execution when it hangs and get a stack trace? What kind of a toolchain do I need to do that?

Either use pycharm community edition (comparably easy) or use stdlib pdb (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) or if you don't like either of those, add print statements at strategic places in the call stack. No space in this box for a tutorial, many already exist and you are in for reading 5-10 pages of text.

If you are developing with an IDE such as VSCode, there are some nice visual debugger (In VSCode its Python Debugger), but it basically uses the python built-in debugger (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) in a visual way. Indeed, as it is interpreted you can have a line by line analysis. The above link show the documentation for it, but I would advise you to use VSCode to be as efficient as possible
